# Retrieving DOM elements in the outer HTML scope from an inner HTML scope

Tags: javascript, html

I was embedding html in a website (template based) and I wanted to manipulate the html outside of my user-defined html. The way it basically works on the site is:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
 </body>
 <html>
  <script>
   document.getElementsByTagName("p").innerHTML = "Greetings World!";
  </script>
 </html>
</html>
```

However, this will only look for "p" elements within the inside html scope. My question is, is there a way to retrieve DOM elements from the inner html scope to the outer html scope? Here's the code I'm working with:

```
<!-- Website HTML -->
<html>
<textarea id="np-text">Hello World!</textarea>
  <!-- Custom HTML -->
  <html>
  <body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Change Value</button>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("np-text").innerHTML += '<span class="hover"><span></span></span>';
    }
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
</html>
```

The main problem is that I cannot change the outer HTML scope in any way; the only html I can define is not in the same scope of what I want to change.

Comment: You have two <html> opening tags and three </html> closing tags. Is there a way you could modify this question and add a code snippet illustrating what you want your HTML / JS to do?

Comment: I will add another example, and change that closing tag for <p>. Don't know why I closed it off with </html>

Comment: Why the nested <html> ? Only one of those per document

Comment: You need to start with proper HTML, otherwise results will be unpredictable. You can not have `html`, `body` or `head` more than once within a document.

Comment: That is the way the site implements user-defined HTML; there is the html that sets up the site structure (cannot change), then inside are any html snippets you define yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "change the outer HTML scope in any way", because **there is not supposed** to be one. The HTML you have included in your question is completely wrong in every way imaginable and will make any HTML validator facepalm.

The only valid way to have an `"inner HTML tree"` inside an existent HTML document is through the use of an `iframe` or `object`. In the case of an `iframe`, in order to be able to access the content of the outer tree, both the content of the parent window and the one of the `iframe` are required to originate from the same domain.

If all of the above is in place, you can access the document of the parent window and subsequently the `textarea` using the following code:

```
parent.document.getElementByID("np-text");
```

In addition, you also have an error in your `JavaScript` code, where you use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p").innerHTML = "Greetings World!";
```

The `getElementsByTagName` method returns an `HTMLCollection`, instead of a single `HTMLElement`, which doesn't have the `innerHTML` method. In order to change the `innerHTML` of a collection of elements, you can use the following code:

```
/* Fetch all 'p' elements. */
var pCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

/* Iterate over every element in the collection and change its content. */
[].forEach.call(pCollection, (element) => element.innerHTML = "Greetings World!");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Your original code:
// document.getElementsByTagName("p").innerHTML = "Greetings World!";

// New code:
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = "Greetings World!";
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I notice you use `getElementsByTagName("p")`, as a short notice you'll see the **s** after `getElements`, with this `s` it meant it'll be an HTMLCollection since you might have many `p` element in your HTML, `[0]` meant the first `<p>` element in this HTML page.

---

For a better code you should do something like this:

```js
document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Greetings World!";
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <p id="greeting">Hello World!</p>


</body>

</html>
<html>
```

You can use `id=""` function to have a safer code since you said it's in template which you might not sure of its position, while `id` in the HTML must be unique, it's proving that you'll find the element/place you want to change and also having a better code.

Comment: `...with this s it meant it'll be an array...` . Absolutely not! `getElementsByTagName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not an `array`.

Comment: You're welcome @Munucial. Just be careful not to misinform people. It's the little things that make the difference 

Comment: @AngelPolitis getting quite rush in that time, I'll make sure the content is correct next time before publishing

Comment: As long as you correct any imperfections in time, it'll be fine.